# Take input from one file and add to other file in particular column

Tags: text-processing

We have two files

```
159
149
```

and

```
2e49.pem,Apr 29 07:07:13 2017 GMT,275
2f69.pem,Apr 29 07:18:21 2017 GMT,275
```

I want to replace the last word, `275`, in the second file with the corresponding line from the first file.

It should look like this:

```
2e49.pem,Apr 29 07:07:13 2017 GMT,159
2f69.pem,Apr 29 07:18:21 2017 GMT,149
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/[^,]*$//' file2 | paste -d '\0' - file1
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '{getline $NF < "file1"; print}' file2
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the bit after the last comma in the second file (including the comma):

```
$ sed 's/,[0-9]*$//' second.txt
2e49.pem,Apr 29 07:07:13 2017 GMT
2f69.pem,Apr 29 07:18:21 2017 GMT
```

Pasting the first file onto the end of each line of that output, with a comma in between:

```
$ paste -d ',' <( sed 's/,[0-9]*$//' second.txt ) first.txt
2e49.pem,Apr 29 07:07:13 2017 GMT,159
2f69.pem,Apr 29 07:18:21 2017 GMT,149
```

This is assuming that your shell understands process substitution with `<( ... )` (`bash` and `ksh93` does).

Note: This is very similar to Stéphane's `sed` solution, but I'm also deleting the comma to avoid the `\0` delimiter to `paste`, and I'm using process substitution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephane and Kusalananda . Both solutions worked perfect.